# Add additional data to Pie Tooltip on Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to add additional data to my pie chart using highcharts. 
Try to explain:
I have a Pie Chart of Browsers:

- Firefox - 10%
- Chrome - 12%
- Explorer - 65%
- Opera - 13%

I would like to add more info to display in the tooltip:
For example:

- Firefox - 10% **of which woman users: 5%**
- Chrome - 12% **of which woman users: 10%**
- Explorer - 65% **of which woman users: 30%**
- Opera - 13% **of which woman users: 5%**

The values I putted are invented, I would like to understand how to customize the tooltip and add some more data to the series.

My [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Maki_help/ac0L1ayq/) code

This is my JS code for the Pie:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                type:'pie'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Browsers'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text:false,
            },

            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },

            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                        style: {
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: "Total",
                colorByPoint: true,
                data: [{
                    name: "Firefox",
                    y: 10,
                }, {
                    name: "Chrome",
                    y: 12,
                }, {
                    name: "Explorer",
                    y: 65,
                }, {
                    name: "Opera",
                    y: 13,
                }]
            }],

        });
    });
</script>
```

This is an image to understand what I would like to do:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: update `pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}% of which women users: {value}</b>'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can put custom data in series and then use in tooltip

```
data: [{
            name: "Firefox",
            y: 10,
    custom:"5% "
        }, {
            name: "Chrome",
            y: 12,
     custom:"10% "
        }, {
            name: "Explorer",
            y: 65,
     custom:"15%"
        }, {
            name: "Opera",
            y: 13,
     custom:"25% "
        }]
```

Use in tooltip

```
  tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b> <br>of which woman users {point.custom}'
    }
```

[See updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/ac0L1ayq/5/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `tooltip.formatter` and extract values from `this.point.options.custom` (where custom if name of field like in examples above)

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter

Answer (score 0):

can try like this

tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '{series.name}: **{point.y}**',

```
      pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b><br/>Totalamount: {point.amount}'

    },
```